# Поиск максимального числа в одномерном массиве Python. Ошибка в коде

Tags: python, массивы

Необходимо с клавиатуры ввести одномерный массив из 10 целых чисел и найти большее из них. В чём именно ошибка кода? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Наверняка же дубликат насчёт нумерации элементов списка с 0, а не с 1

Comment: @CrazyElf, ага, уже не дубликат, а 100500пликат явно)

Comment: @Глеб Тогда и нужно искать, к чему он дубликат и закрывать как дубликат. Потом всё-равно закроют и от ответа толком не будет особого )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный код для решения этой задачи:

```
lst = [int(input()) for _ in range(10)]
print(max(lst))
```

Ну или так (однострочник):

```
print(max(int(input()) for _ in range(10)))
```

В вашем коде, очевидно, ошибка в том, что в массиве 10 чисел, а вы ссылаетесь на *одиннадцатое* (индекс 10). Думаю, если изменить строку `while i <= 10` на `while i < 10`, код заработает. Чтобы можно было точнее определить вашу проблему, пожалуйста, вставьте код текстом.

Помимо этого, в вашем коде есть много мелких нарушений. Например, очень плохая практика делать переменные `i` и `I` в коде рядом. `Max` очень напоминает по названию аналогичную встроенную функцию питона, так что в будущем подобные переменные называйте как-то типа `cur_max`. Иначе запутаетесь моментально.

Comment: Ошибки в использовании "i" и "I" нет.  Ошибка только в том, что я ссылался на 11 число.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @ДанилаМастер, про `I` — это не ошибка, а просто серьезное нарушение стиля)

Comment: Квадратные скобки в однострочнике не нужны. Сгенерированную последовательность можно напрямую передать в max() без промежуточного создания списка

Comment: @АлексейР, верно, не подумал. Теперь исправил.